# How to get specific key value from this type array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, object

this is the output i am getting by using curl API. But i am not getting the value based on specific key. Can anyone help me to get the key value?

```
{"Stages":[{"Sid":"15463","Snm":"Warm-Up Matches","Scd":"warm-up-matches","Cid":"12","Cnm":"ICC Men's One-Day World Cup","Csnm":"ICC Men's One-Day World Cup","Ccd":"icc-mens-one-day-world-cup","Scu":1,"Sds":"Warm-Up Matches","Chi":0,"Shi":0,"Ccdiso":"NON","Sdn":"Warm-Up Matches","Events":[{"Eid":"1064978","Pids":{"8":"1064978","11":"58729","12":"SBTE_29426843"},"Sids":{"8":"15463","11":"3290","12":"SBTC3_211432"},"Tr1":"0","Tr2":"0","Tr2C1":0,"Tr2CW1":0,"Tr2CO1":0.1,"T1":[{"Nm":"Afghanistan","ID":"86113","Abr":"AFG","tbd":0,"Gd":1,"Pids":{"11":["95"],"12":["SBTP_241802"],"8":["86113"]},"HasVideo":false}],"T2":[{"Nm":"Sri Lanka","ID":"86129","Abr":"SRI","tbd":0,"Gd":1,"Pids":{"11":["7"],"12":["SBTP_374797"],"8":["86129"]},"HasVideo":false}],"Esid":33,"EpsL":"Play in progress","Epr":1,"Ecov":0,"Et":151,"EtTx":"Non Official One Day","ECo":"Sri Lanka are 0 for 0 with 49.5 overs left","Ebat":2,"TPa":1,"TCho":2,"Esd":20231003013000,"Ese":20231003013000,"Exd":1,"LuUT":20231003013100,"Eact":1,"EO":2097767,"EOX":2097767,"IncsX":0,"ComX":1,"LuX":1,"StatX":0,"SubsX":0,"SDFowX":0,"SDInnX":1,"LuC":1,"Ehid":0,"Spid":73,"Stg":{"Sid":"15463","Snm":"Warm-Up Matches","Scd":"warm-up-matches","Cid":"12","Cnm":"ICC Men's One-Day World Cup","Csnm":"ICC Men's One-Day World Cup","Ccd":"icc-mens-one-day-world-cup","Scu":1,"Sds":"Warm-Up Matches","Chi":0,"Shi":0,"Ccdiso":"NON","Sdn":"Warm-Up Matches"},"Pid":8},{"Eid":"1064973","Pids":{"8":"1064973","11":"58731","12":"SBTE_29435131"},"Sids":{"8":"15463","11":"3290","12":"SBTC3_211432"},"Tr1":"0","Tr2":"0","Tr2C1":17,"Tr2CW1":0,"Tr2CO1":4.1,"T1":[{"Nm":"Pakistan","ID":"86130","Abr":"PAK","tbd":0,"Gd":1,"Pids":{"11":["5"],"12":["SBTP_141660"],"8":["86130"]},"HasVideo":false}],"T2":[{"Nm":"Australia","ID":"86103","Abr":"AUS","tbd":0,"Gd":1,"Pids":{"11":["1"],"12":["SBTP_1109071"],"8":["86103"]},"HasVideo":false}],"Esid":33,"EpsL":"Play in progress","Epr":1,"Ecov":0,"Et":151,"EtTx":"Non Official One Day","ECo":"Australia are 17 for 0 with 45.5 overs left","Ebat":2,"TPa":2,"TCho":1,"Esd":20231003013000,"Ese":20231003013000,"Exd":1,"LuUT":20231003011205,"Eact":1,"EO":2097767,"EOX":2097767,"IncsX":0,"ComX":1,"LuX":1,"StatX":0,"SubsX":0,"SDFowX":0,"SDInnX":1,"LuC":1,"Ehid":0,"Spid":73,"Stg":{"Sid":"15463","Snm":"Warm-Up Matches","Scd":"warm-up-matches","Cid":"12","Cnm":"ICC Men's One-Day World Cup","Csnm":"ICC Men's One-Day World Cup","Ccd":"icc-mens-one-day-world-cup","Scu":1,"Sds":"Warm-Up Matches","Chi":0,"Shi":0,"Ccdiso":"NON","Sdn":"Warm-Up Matches"},"Pid":8}]},{"Sid":"15327","Snm":"Men's Asian Games Twenty20","Scd":"mens-asian-games-twenty-twenty","Cid":"14","Cnm":"Twenty20 Internationals","Csnm":"Twenty20 Intl.","Ccd":"intl-t20","Scu":1,"Sds":"Men's Asian Games Twenty20","Chi":0,"Shi":0,"Ccdiso":"NON","Sdn":"Men's Asian Games Twenty20","Events":[{"Eid":"1056620","Pids":{"8":"1056620","11":"58675","12":"SBTE_29442095"},"Sids":{"8":"15327","11":"3285"},"Tr1":"0","Tr2":"0","Tr1C1":160,"Tr2C1":31,"Tr1CW1":10,"Tr2CW1":2,"Tr1CO1":20.0,"Tr2CO1":6.0,"T1":[{"Nm":"Pakistan","ID":"86130","Abr":"PAK","tbd":0,"Gd":1,"Pids":{"11":["5"],"12":["SBTP_141660"],"8":["86130"]},"HasVideo":false}],"T2":[{"Nm":"Hong Kong","ID":"86193","Abr":"HON","tbd":0,"Gd":1,"Pids":{"11":["18"],"12":["SBTP_242248"],"8":["86193"]},"HasVideo":false}],"Esid":33,"EpsL":"Play in progress","Epr":1,"Ecov":0,"ErnInf":"Quarter Final 2","Et":100,"EtTx":"Twenty20","ECo":"Hong Kong need 130 runs to win from 14.0 overs","Ebat":2,"TPa":2,"TCho":2,"Esd":20231002230000,"Exd":1,"LuUT":20231002224645,"Eact":1,"EO":6815847,"EOX":6815847,"IncsX":0,"ComX":0,"LuX":1,"StatX":0,"SubsX":0,"SDFowX":1,"SDInnX":1,"LuC":1,"Ehid":0,"Spid":73,"Stg":{"Sid":"15327","Snm":"Men's Asian Games Twenty20","Scd":"mens-asian-games-twenty-twenty","Cid":"14","Cnm":"Twenty20 Internationals","Csnm":"Twenty20 Intl.","Ccd":"intl-t20","Scu":1,"Sds":"Men's Asian Games Twenty20","Chi":0,"Shi":0,"Ccdiso":"NON","Sdn":"Men's Asian Games Twenty20"},"Pid":8}]},{"Sid":"14819","Snm":"Marsh Sheffield Shield","Scd":"marsh-sheffield-shield","Cid":"28","Cnm":"Australia","Csnm":"Australia","Ccd":"australia","Scu":0,"Chi":0,"Shi":0,"Ccdiso":"NON","Sdn":"Marsh Sheffield Shield","Events":[{"Eid":"1012896","Pids":{"8":"1012896","11":"58441","12":"SBTE_29441287"},"Sids":{"8":"14819","11":"3270"},"Tr1":"0","Tr2":"0","Tr1C1":307,"Tr2C1":94,"Tr1CW1":10,"Tr2CW1":1,"Tr1CO1":63.4,"Tr2CO1":28.0,"T1":[{"Nm":"South Australia","ID":"86297","Abr":"SOU","tbd":0,"Gd":1,"Pids":{"11":["155"],"12":["SBTP_282642"],"8":["86297"]},"HasVideo":false}],"T2":[{"Nm":"Tasmania","ID":"86292","Abr":"TAS","tbd":0,"Gd":1,"Pids":{"11":["298"],"12":["SBTP_223704"],"8":["86292"]},"HasVideo":false}],"Esid":132,"EpsL":"Stumps - day 1","Epr":1,"Ecov":0,"Et":170,"EtTx":"Domestic First Class","ECo":"Tasmania trail South Australia by 213 runs with 9 wickets remaining","Ebat":2,"TPa":1,"TCho":1,"Esd":20231002170000,"Exd":4,"LuUT":20231002162806,"Eact":1,"EO":6816359,"EOX":6816359,"IncsX":0,"ComX":1,"LuX":1,"StatX":0,"SubsX":0,"SDFowX":1,"SDInnX":1,"LuC":1,"Ehid":0,"Spid":73,"Stg":{"Sid":"14819","Snm":"Marsh Sheffield Shield","Scd":"marsh-sheffield-shield","Cid":"28","Cnm":"Australia","Csnm":"Australia","Ccd":"australia","Scu":0,"Chi":0,"Shi":0,"Ccdiso":"NON","Sdn":"Marsh Sheffield Shield"},"Pid":8}]}]}
```

Comment: let me check - ADyson

Comment: That link teaches you how to understand the json and the data you get when you decode it, so you can then apply the knowledge to get whatever specific data you want from the data shown in your question. So I would be surprised if it doesn't help you.

Comment: it further dividing it into numbers of arrays . thank your for your reply it helping me but not fully and sorry i am newbie in coding.

Comment: You haven't said which specific key you are trying to get the value of. Try writing some code to get that value based on the duplicate and if you still have problems, ask another question.

Comment: `it further dividing it into numbers of arrays`...what is? `json_decode` alone doesn't divide anything, it simply turns the JSON string into a usable PHP data structure so you can easily access the data you need. The above JSON will be decoded into an object which contains a property called "Stages", which is an array, with objects in each index of that array, and further subdivisions within that, as per the JSON notation. You haven't shown us what you tried based on what you've learned so far, and as Nick says you also haven't actually  told us which specific data you're trying to access.

Comment: thanks alot ADyson as you said (apply the knowledge) so i apply and getting values i want. Your reply is works for me. :)